# Why was the name "Marty" given to this character?

Tags: christmas-with-the-kranks

In *Christmas with the Kranks* there is character introduced late into the film that seems to know everyone, but none of the characters don't seem to recognize.

At the Kranks' Christmas party the character reveals his name to be "Marty", yet the other characters still can not place how they know him. A bit later Marty stops a burglar while dressed in Santa suit, which reveals he was the man trying to sell umbrellas earlier in the film and supposedly explain how he knew everyone.

However at the end of the film we see Marty drive away in VW Bug that then turns out to be:

> Santa's sleigh being pulled by flying reindeer and that Marty is actually the real Santa Claus.

So if this was Marty's true identity, why did he use the name Marty, when typically his "common name" would be Chris or Nick (or similar)? Was it try to obfuscate this true identity?

Comment: Why would his common name be Chris?  What's wrong with Martin?  Do all Prime Ministers need to be named "George?"

Comment: @DavidW I am going based on the legend of the character of Marty's true identity. I realized I forget the other obvious choice!

Comment: It could be a nod to [St. Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Martin%27s_Day), another gift-giving Germanic saint.

Comment: That's Marty!  You know Marty!  Everyone knows Marty!